# Batch script - Wrong If syntax

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to check the text in my created array, if I am not using "if" every thing works and i can use "echo" but when I add the "if" command I get "wrong syntax"

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set i=0

for /f "delims= " %%a in ('command') do (

set /A i+=1
set list[!i!]=%%~a
)

set Filesx=%i%

rem Display array elements
for /L %%i in (1,1,%Filesx%) do (
    if list[%%i] =="some ttext"
        echo !list[%%i]!
)
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be parentheses around the `echo !list[%%i]!` command, too?

Comment: dont thinks so, anyway, i added them and the result is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider changing your script accordingly:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "i=0"
For /F %%A In ('command') Do (Set/A i+=1
    Set list[!i!]=%%~A)

Rem Display array elements
For /L %%A In (1,1,%i%) Do If /I "!list[%%A]!"=="some ttext" Echo !list[%%A]!

Pause
```

*In your script you needed to change `if list[%%i]` to `If /I "!list[%%i]!"`*

```bat
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set i=0

for /f "delims= " %%a in ('command') do (

    set /A i+=1
    set list[!i!]=%%~a
)

set Filesx=%i%

rem Display array elements
for /L %%i in (1,1,%Filesx%) do (
    if /i "!list[%%i]!" =="some ttext" (
        echo !list[%%i]!
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

An `if` statement requires an *exact* match (for `==` or `equ`) so if you quote one side, you need to quote the other.

also, the action for the if-true condition must be on the same physical line as the `if`

Comment: and with my addendum...??